# Autodesk Maya LT 2020 -- no rendering menu

Tags: user-interface, rendering, maya, autodesk

I'm having a strange issue with Maya I can't find a solution for online. There's no rendering buttons in the rendering icons menu, only these two buttons, one for editing shading relationships and the other for pausing "Viewpoint 2 display update":

[image: shelf]

There's also none in the menu set menu:

[image: menu set menu]

There's also no rendering settings window option in the windows menu:

[image: windows menu]

nor are there any rendering options in the windows preferences:

[image: windows preferences]

Any idea? I've tried this version of maya on two computers now (a lenovo ideapad flex 4 and a panasonic toughbook cf-32) and am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently LT doesn't provide rendering, lol. Ok. The problem is, Autodesk isn't giving me full access even though my institution is supposed to be provided it. Anyway, problem solved.

[image: Autodesk Help Forum]